# Tensorflow BeamSearchDecoder how to handle the initial_state

Tags: tensorflow

I write code based on tensorflow seq2seq API to construct a beam search decoder, and ends up with error at below line of code

```
decoder_initial_state = decoder_initial_state.clone(cell_state=encoded_states)
```

where encoded_states and decoder_initial_state are generated by

```
encoded_tupple, encoded_states = bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell_fw, lstm_cell_bw, inputs, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=input_sequence_lengths)
encoded_states = tile_batch(encoded_states, multiplier=self.beam_width) 

decoder_initial_state = rnn_cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
```

the error I got is

ValueError: The two structures don't have the same number of elements.

First structure (6 elements): AttentionWrapperState(cell_state=(LSTMStateTuple(c=, h=),), attention=, time=, alignments=, alignment_history=(), attention_state=)

Second structure (8 elements): AttentionWrapperState(cell_state=(LSTMStateTuple(c=, h=), LSTMStateTuple(c=, h=)), attention=, time=, alignments=, alignment_history=(), attention_state=)

I guess this is because I did not pack the encoded_states correctly before passing into clone() method.

what should I do, thanks!

Comment: and actually I am still thinking, given encoder is based on bidirectional rnn, so we have fw_encoded_states and bw_encoded_states inside encoded_states tuple,  while decoder is uni-directional, I am wondering whether I should only pass fw_encoded_state into clone() as decoder initial state?

Comment: also, in case I have several lstm layers in my encoder, how to manipulate encoded_states